# Add class to last element on click JQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Basically i'm creating a little to do list app, at the minute I append new list items to a container on button click, this creates the list effect.

What I want to do is add a class to the last element of the list, using last:child works for this but what I need it to do is update the last element when new elements are added, so lets say I have 5 items in a list so the 5th item has class last, when I add a new item I want to remove the class from the old last item and add it to the new last item (that make sense?)

Here's the code I have so far..

```
<div id="list_container">
    <div id="to_do">
        <ul id="tasks" style="padding:0;">      
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

var items = [];

// Add new item
$('#add_btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var list_item = $('#new_item').val();

    // Validation
    if(list_item == ""){
        $('#new_item').addClass('empty');
    }else{ 
        $('#new_item').removeClass('empty').addClass('normal');
        items.push(list_item);
        var lastEl = items[items.length-1];
        $('ul#tasks').append('<li><input type="text" class="to_do_item" value="' + lastEl + '"/></input></li>');
    }

    // Clear input field after adding
    $('#new_item').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('');

});
```

Anyone know how to achieve this? I'm think it can't be that difficult but I can't seem to think straight right now..

Comment: From your jQuery I suspect you have duplicated ID's in your html. Don't do that.

Comment: Where abouts you looking? the id new_item is the input box if that's where you're thinking? If not feel free to point out as it would have just been a mistake :)

Comment: `$('#new_item').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')` makes no sense unless you have more than one element with that id

Comment: Sorry, I think that's old code that I no longer need!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
var lastEl = items[items.length-1];
$('ul#tasks li').removeClass('last');
$('ul#tasks').append('<li class="last"><input type="text" class="to_do_item" value="' + lastEl + '"/></input></li>');
...
```

Comment: Sorry my code may be a bit misleading, the #new_item is for validation if the input is empty, it basically adds a coloured border if you don't enter anything and press add, there's probably an easier way to do this but adding or removing a class was the only way I could think of doing it..

Comment: ok. I rewrote my answer. You're doing the adding the border thing perfectly fine.

Comment: This seems logical to me, after testing it though it doesn't seem to work, the class last gets added first time round but after that it just removes all classes and doesn't proceed to add the class last anymore

Comment: It's working now, thanks! I had old code I was playing around with that was interrupting the code you provided, thank  you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.last').removeClass('last')
$('#new_item').addClass('last');
```

this guarentees nothing has the class 'last', then applies .last to the new li

I would even recommend `$(this)` instead of `$('#new_item')`

Comment: $(this) != $('#new_item'), $(this)==$('#add_btn')

Comment: that's correct , I didn't want to re-write the whole code, but if you can get it in such a way that $(this) is your new li , then you can remove the duplicate id's and such